# How to prove $f(a) \in f(A)$ imply $a \in A$?

Tags: analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be an injective map. Let $A\subset X$ . How to prove  if $a \notin A$, then $f(a) \notin f(A)$? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5):

Since $f(a)\in f(A)$ there is $b\in A$ s.t. $f(a)=f(b)$. Using injectivity of $f$ allow you to conclude.